# Pyinstaller App Labelled as a Trojan on other Pcs

Tags: python, pyinstaller

The Issue is as it reads from the title. Now I know that there have been posts about this already, but I am searching for a definitive solution, self signing is not an option for me. I am making a project and want to send it to my IT teacher, but when my friend tried to run the app, It is labelled as Trojan by Windows Defender and Instantly removed. I really don't want to go into the trouble and try to explain to my teacher why it is detected as a Severe Threat and instruct her to turn off her antivirus. I hope you can help me, Cheers!

Comment: Well, I am going to try, I have already seen this post but this is the solution I want to try at the very last. I guess if there are no other ways to do this I have no choice. Thanks, cheers!

Comment: Update: IT WORKED :D!